# replacing several characters using javascript replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace all the occurrences of accented characters À, Á, Â, Ã, Ä, Å with "A" using javascript replace ( For example, "ÀNÁPIÂLÃZÄ" would be rendered to "ANAPIALAZA").
I tried:

```
var re = /À||Á||À||Á||Â||Ã||Ä||Å/g; 
name =  name.replace(re,"A");
```

and

```
var  re = /(ÀÁÂÃÄÅ)/g;
name =  name.replace(re,"A");
```

I not sure how to express the desired rule in regex pattern.
Thanks

Comment: square brackets; `/[abc]/g` means any `a` or `b` or `c`.

Comment: Your first attempt should have worked, except you should only have a single pipe between the characters, not two pipes.

Comment: I see. A single | gets it working. Thanks

Comment: Note that there are more than one way to render `ÀÁ` (not sure about other characters, but it may also applies): either a single character, or a base character plus a combining diacritics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square [ ] brackets will solve your problem.

```
var  re = /[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]/g;
name =  name.replace(re,"A");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y2a6x/

Comment: Thanks for giving that link.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[]` square brackets, like this:

```
/[ÀÁÀÁÂÃÄÅ]/g
```

The problem with your first `||` example, by the way, is that you should only use one `|` in regexes.